# Keep DialogFragment open until user inputs are valid Android?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I subclass DialogFragment to show an input field to the user.

If the user does not provide any input I want to keep the dialog open and show an error on the input field. The dialog is dismissed automatically when the user press the positive "Save" button no matter if the input field is empty or not.

How can I override this default behaviour?

code snippet (full code is very long, but you get the idea):

```
public class SurveySingleQuestionDialog extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    return (builder.setTitle(mArgs.getString("question_body"))
            .setView(layout)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, this)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show());

}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

if(validInputs()){

//dismiss dialog and save inputs

}
else{

//show error on input field

}

}

}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: have you added breakpoints to check the results of validInputs()?

Comment: that works fine, I am able to see the red exclamation mark while the dialog is closing...and my db function is not (correctly) triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the setNegative / setPositive buttons are designed to dismiss the dialogue after the callback has returned. You would probably be better including your own buttons in your view and dismissing the dialogue yourself

Comment: that is something I really would like to avoid...it looks to me it would be re-inventing the wheel... :/

Comment: @Mirko this is not really re-inventing the wheel. The documentation for the `DialogFragment` class gives the explicit freedom to implement your own UI and doesn't restrict you from implementing your own buttons behavior